# Windows Call Api with Curl with certificates

Tags: curl

I try to call my api on my windows machine.I tried request via over curl which is exist in gitbash I got certificate error

```
curl  --cert mypc\mysample.crt --key mypc\mysample.key --cacert mypc\mysample.crt https://localhost:8073/api/hello
```

> curl: (58) schannel: Failed to import cert file mypc\mysample.crt,
> last error is 0x80092002

Git version:git version 2.41.0.windows.1

Answer (score 0):

This error related about curl version ,for example version 8.1.2 not support crt usage anymore.
There are two possible solution reduce curl version(security risk) or use pem certificates.